# Naive pointer arithmetic merge sort returning errors

Tags: c, pointers, mergesort

Trying to implement a naive merge sort using pointer arithmetic, but it's returning non-sense results. I'm following the convention that `l` is the leftmost valid index and `r` is the rightmost valid index.

The input is  `5 1 3 2 4` but it returns: `0 1 0 2 5` and naturally the expected output is `1 2 3 4 5`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergeptr(int *array, int l, int m, int r)
{
    int tmp[r - l + 1];
    int *tptr = &(tmp[0]);
    int *lptr = &(array[l]);
    int *rptr = &(array[m]);

    /* Find the smallest in each side */
    while ((lptr < &array[m]) && (rptr < &array[r]))
        if (*lptr <= *rptr) *tptr++ = *lptr++;
        else                *tptr++ = *rptr++;

    /* Copy the remaining */
    while (lptr < &array[m]) *tptr++ = *lptr++;
    while (rptr < &array[r]) *tptr++ = *rptr++;

    /* Copy back */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (r-l+1); ++i)
        array[l+i] = tmp[i];
}

void merge_sort(int *array, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        merge_sort(array, l, m);
        merge_sort(array, m + 1, r);
        mergeptr(array, l, m, r);
   }
}

int main(void) { 
    int values[5] = { 5, 1, 3, 2, 4 };

    merge_sort(&values[0], 0, 4);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to decouple those coupled pointers as `*tptr = *lptr; tptr++; lptr++;`. To check if something as happening in wrong order but didn't change the outputs. Can't see where the the algorithm is failing.

Comment: did you try to debug it? Add some additional printfs in your functions to show you debug trace. That is the way of lerning C

Comment: "[32, 52) 'values' (line 34) <== Memory access at offset 52 overflows this variable"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be careful when you are dealing with boundaries.
It seems your `merge_sort` function is dealing with the range `[l, r)` (including `l`, excluding `r`), so:

- The element `m` shouldn't be execluded: `merge_sort(array, m+1, r);` should be `merge_sort(array, m, r);`
- No sorting is required when there are only 1 element: `if (l < r) {` should be `if (l + 1 < r) {`
- `r - l + 1` and `r-l+1` in the function `mergeptr` should be `r - l` and `r-l`.

fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergeptr(int *array, int l, int m, int r)
{
    int tmp[r - l];
    int *tptr = tmp;
    int *lptr = array + l;
    int *rptr = array + m;

    /* Find the smallest in each side */
    while( (lptr < (array + m)) && (rptr < (array + r)))
        if( *lptr <= *rptr) *tptr++ = *lptr++;
        else                *tptr++ = *rptr++;

    /* Copy the remaining */
    while(lptr < (array + m)) *tptr++ = *lptr++;
    while(rptr < (array + r)) *tptr++ = *rptr++;

    /* Copy back */
    for(size_t i = 0; i < (r-l); ++i)
        array[l+i] = tmp[i];
}

void merge_sort(int *array, int l, int r) {
    if (l + 1 < r) {
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        merge_sort(array, l, m);
        merge_sort(array, m, r);
        mergeptr(array, l, m, r);
   }
}

int main(void) { 
    int values[5] = { 5, 1, 3, 2, 4 };

    merge_sort(values, 0, 5);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%d ", values[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```&array[r]``` is undefined behavior right? I guess you need to make some changes?

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Having pointer point at one past the last element should be valid, according to [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.7 Additive operators.

Comment: It is a pity so many tutorials and teachers advocate the convention that both boundaries be included. This results in cumbersome and error prone code. Making `r` excluded allows for much simpler code as can be seen here.